# ionic/angular $state.go gives blank screen for login page

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement a login/auth page using firebase for my ionic app, but am encountering some issues.

I use tabs in the main part of my app, but when I try and redirect a user to the login page (hiding my tabbed view), the login page shows as being blank despite the state and url being directed correctly.  Here is where I declare my states and tabs:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // setup an abstract state for the auth section
  .state('auth', {
    url: '/auth',
    abstract: true,
  })

  .state('auth.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'main-view1': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/auth/login.html',
        controller: 'LogInCtrl'
      }
    },
    data: {
      authenticate: false
    }
  })

  .state('auth.signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    views: {
      'main-view2': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/auth/signup.html',
        controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
      }
    },
    data: {
      authenticate: false
    }
  })

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'tab-home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }
    },
    data: {
      authenticate: true
    }
    });
});
```

My redirection takes place here within the run function:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, AuthService) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
    AuthService.userIsLoggedIn().then(function(response)
    {
      if(response === true)
      {
        $state.go('tab.home');
      }
      else
      {
        $state.go('auth.login');
      }
    });

    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });

  // UI Router Authentication Check
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if (toState.data.authenticate)
    {
      AuthService.userIsLoggedIn().then(function(response)
      {
        if(response === false)
        {
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go('auth.login');
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

Lastly, my templates/auth/login.html file looks like this:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Log In</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="facebookLogin()">Login with Facebook</button>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-center">
        <h4 class="text-center">OR</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form name="login_form" class="form-container" novalidate>
      <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" required>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" required>
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="login(user)" ng-disabled="login_form.$invalid">Login</button>
    </form>
    <button class="button button-block button-clear button-positive button-small" ui-sref="auth.signup">
      Sign Up
    </button>
    <div ng-show="errors">
      <p class="message error" ng-repeat="error in errors"><b>[{{error.code}}]</b> {{error.msg}}</p>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong when implementing the login page?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with a herarchy approach for the login/sign up section. You should create simple states without auth. (It'seems no mandatory). If you decide to remove it, you need to remove the ui-view references, "main-view1" and "main-view2", because those indicate where the view is going to be loaded and need to be the declared inside the parent's template.

And if you still want to keep an author parent view, what you need is to create a template for the abstract state and declare a div with the ui-view attribute, give it a name like "main-view" and then change both your auth.login and auth.signup ui-view reference to "main-view".